# Webflux upload large files cause Java heap space

Tags: spring-webflux, large-files

Probably not many developers are facing the problem the same as me. 
But I want to share the solution which I had been solved for almost 1 month. 
I use Kubernetes and docker-compose, this Webflux service (container) is set the memory limit 1g `mem_limit: 1g` I am not allowed to increase the memory limit.

`coRouter` has been used as a controller which is in the container.

```kotlin
@Configuration
class WebController(
) {

    @Bean
    fun endpoints() = coRouter {
        contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).nest {
            POST("/uploadFile") { requestParm ->
                requestParm.awaitMultipartData().multipartFormData["file"]?.first()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I upload files using the API
`http://localhost:9004/uploadFile` 100MB, 10 files (using JS Ajax) 
It will produce `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` because it doesn't have enough memory. 
Whenever you call `requestParm.awaitMultipartData()` it will stream those bytes into memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that, my current code will store the upload files in memory directly.
There are 2 ways to solve this problem.

- **1st way**, add `@EnableWebFlux` on your Router or Controller

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
class WebController(
) { }
```

- **2nd way**, extending from `DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration` to your Router or Controller 
  Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-config-advanced-java

```kotlin
@Configuration
class WebController(
): DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration() { }
```

Why does it solve the uploading large file problem?

These 2 ways above will be automatically used a supper class's method 
`configureHttpMessageCodecs(configurer: ServerCodecConfigurer)` 
 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-codecs-multipart

> By default, the DefaultPartHttpMessageReader is used, but this can be changed through the ServerCodecConfigurer. For more information about the DefaultPartHttpMessageReader, refer to to the javadoc of DefaultPartHttpMessageReader.

As you can see `ServerCodecConfigurer` will use DefaultPartHttpMessageReader by default.

`DefaultPartHttpMessageReader` has this important properties `MaxInMemorySize` (if memory full, store in disk)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/multipart/DefaultPartHttpMessageReader.html#setMaxInMemorySize-int-

> Configure the maximum amount of memory allowed per part. When the limit is exceeded:
> file parts are written to a temporary file.
> non-file parts are rejected with DataBufferLimitException.
> By default this is set to 256K.

The default memory for uploading files is 256K 
It will save those files to disk for temporary if the memory is full.

You can custom the memory to store size files also [Spring WebFlux: set max file(s) size for uploading files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57424649/spring-webflux-set-max-files-size-for-uploading-files/59538777#59538777)